# Better Solution for turning events ON and OFF for Discord.js + MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, discord.js

I have a public discord.js bot with MongoDB / Mongoose implemented.

So I've got a lot of events such as `guildMemberAdd`, `guildBanAdd`, etc. and my bot's a public server bot.

Now, if I wanted an ON / OFF thing for such events (since not everyone needs to primarily use my `guildMemberAdd` event for something like welcoming someone) how would I be able to do it?

I have one solution in mind, which is include every single event that my bot has inside a guildConfig model for MongoDB, and have a boolean to indicate ON / OFF. Then include a return statement that stops the event if the event is turned OFF (false in MongoDB).

Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an array to your guildConfig mongodb model called something like enabledEvents and add events to it.
Then to check if an event is enabled you just check if an element (the event) is inside that array.

```
enabledEvents = ["guildMemberAdd", "guildBanAdd"];
if (enabledEvents.includes("guildMemberAdd")) {
 // do stuff
};
```